# django-autocomplete-light - how to return a different field then a models primary key?

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-select2, django-crispy-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I am using django-autocomplete-light

in a form for a model I want to use autocomplete on one of its field. the field is not a foreignkey or something, but just a integer field and for autocomplete I would actually like to use the same model then the form I am filling.

The query set from autocomplete however returns the ID and I want to fill the field "projektnummer".

Any clue how I can setup autocomplete so that it returns not the primary key of the model but some other field?

also it seems that I get a wired failure from crispy forms when I use the autocomplete-widget on the integer field.

models.py

```
class KombiPublikation(models.Model):
    typid = models.ForeignKey('KombiPublikationsTypMedium', verbose_name='Outputtyp', db_column='typid') # publikationstyp.id or publikationstypinfo.typid
    [...]
    projektnummer = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Projektnr.', default=0, blank=True)
[...]
```

views.py

```
class SearchProjectinFormAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = KombiPublikation.objects.filter(typid__in=[222, 223, 224]).filter(zeigen=1)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(Q(projektnummer__contains=self.q))

        return qs
```

forms.py

```
class KombiPublikationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = KombiPublikation
        #fields = []
        exclude = ['pub_sprache']
        widgets = {
            'typid': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='output:typ-autocomplete', forward=['typtyp']),
            'projektnummer': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='output:projekt-form-autocomplete'),
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer.

You actually have to override get_result_value from the base autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView to return the variable you want from the resulting object. :)

However, I still cannot use the autocomplete widget in my crispy forms form - opened a new question for that (see ['list' object has no attribute 'queryset' error when adding a autocomplete field to a model-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048400/list-object-has-no-attribute-queryset-error-when-adding-a-autocomplete-field))

```
def get_result_value(self, result):
    """Return the value of a result."""
    return result.pk #change pk to the variable of your choice
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you're making a query out of the `KombiPublikationForm` class in your `forms.py` instead of making it from `BasePublikation` in your `models.py`, try

```
class SearchProjectinFormAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = BasePublikation.objects.filter(typid__in=[222, 223, 224]).filter(zeigen=1)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(projektnummer__contains=self.q)

        return qs
```

On the other hand we might want to look on how does the `KombiPublikationsTypMedium` class look like in order to know how would the query might behave.

Hope this helps!!

--edit--

Try getting rid of the Q statement: `qs = qs.filter(projektnummer__contains=self.q)`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Base publication is the abstract base class that contains the field. I wanted to shield my question from this unnecessary complexity. Just forgot to rename it accordingly.