# how o make django-autocomplete light return selected text not id

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I have a simple form which lets a user select his `country`, `state` and `district` and redisplays the selected data.

Everything works as expected apart from the fact that **what is displayed is not the "text" but "ids" of the selected data**.

Expectation: **You belong to India, Punjab, Jalandhar. Me too. ;)**

Output: **You belong to 1, 2, 4. Me too. ;)**

```
# my form

class MyInfoForm(forms.Form):
country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Country.objects.all(),
    widget=autocomplete.ListSelect2(
        url='country-autocomplete',
    )
)
state = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=State.objects.all(),
    widget=autocomplete.ListSelect2(
        url='state-autocomplete',
        forward=(forward.Field('country'),)
    )
)
district = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=District.objects.all(),
    widget=autocomplete.ListSelect2(
        url='district-autocomplete',
        forward=(forward.Field('state'),)
    )
)

# my view which handles MyInfoForm

class CountryView(FormView):
template_name = 'home.html'
form_class = MyInfoForm
success_url = '/thanks/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    print("Request :", self.request.POST)
    country = self.request.POST["country"]
    state = self.request.POST["state"]
    district = self.request.POST["district"]
    msg = "You belong to {country}, {state}, {district}. Me too. ;)".format(
        country=country, state=state, district=district)
    return HttpResponse(msg)


# other auto-complete views (similar to official tutorials)

class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
def get_queryset(self):
    # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Country.objects.none()

    qs = Country.objects.all()

    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(country_name__istartswith=self.q)

    return qs


 class StateAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
 def get_queryset(self):
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return State.objects.none()

    qs = State.objects.all()

    country = self.forwarded.get('country', None)

    if country:
        qs = qs.filter(country_name=country)

    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(state_name__istartswith=self.q)

    return qs


class DistrictAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
def get_queryset(self):
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return District.objects.none()

    qs = District.objects.all()

    state = self.forwarded.get('state', None)

    if state:
        qs = qs.filter(state_name=state)

    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(district_name__istartswith=self.q)

    return qs

 # models 

class Country(models.Model):
country_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.country_name


class State(models.Model):
country_name = models.ForeignKey(Country)
state_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.state_name


class District(models.Model):
state_name = models.ForeignKey(State)
district_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.district_name
```

I applied what is mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40048134/8414030) answer but no gain. Applying this solution makes no option to populate in `state` and `district`.

Comment: try `get_country_display` in your template where you are displaying choices and in view add `()` like `get_country_display()`

Answer (score 0):

Just call the object, in your form valid. Autocomplete light is configured to return the ID which is the default behaviour of Select widgets.

```
def form_valid(self, form):)
    country_pk = self.request.POST["country"]
   state_pk = self.request.POST["state"]
   district_pk = self.request.POST["district"]
   country = Country.objects.get(pk = country_pk)
   #--- district
   #---- state
   #if you have defined a str method you can just proceed as
   #as below since the render will call __str__ else
   #you can use country.name, state.name, district.name
   msg = "You belong to {country}, {state}, {district}. Me too. 
   ;)".format(country=country, state=state, district=district)
```